# Can a star emits laser?

Tags: laser, stars

I know if I pump enough energy to a bunch of electrons so that they are all in their excited states, then I can introduce some photons to start off a chain reaction resulting in simulated emission. Can a star do so too?

Comment: This question does not seem to be an exact duplicate. It specifically asks whether stars can emit laser. The other question deals with any possible scenario and would therefore not necessarily refer to stars in particular.

Comment: @flippiefanus The [Community close vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250922#250930) indicates that user6760 agreed that the proposed duplicate answers their question. That's independent of whether this should get reopened, but in my view it's close enough to be a duplicate.

Comment: The way I understand the point of Physics SE is to provide answers, not only for those that pose them, but for anybody having the same question.

Comment: @flippiefanus yes, hence why this question has been linked to another which has a valid answer.

Comment: The point that I've raised in my original comment is that the answer provided in the linked answer does not address the current question for reasons that I've tried to explain.